# How to pass data between iOS and TvOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, tvos

I am making an application where I want iOS application to connect to TvOS app and send data across. What is the best way of communication?

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Probably should be more specific about the type and amount of data

Comment: Let's say I want to pass a dictionary between two.

Comment: Try a socket solution. I would try something like GCDAsyncSocket.

Comment: I think I would try CoreBluetooth first and see if it met my needs.

Comment: I need around 4-5 devices to be connected at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by standard networking like (TCP/IP), create server in TVOS app, and then find server from iOS app and once connection is created you can transfer data, you can use [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket) for this purpose.  You can also use `iCloud` if you want.